When to say Bismillah
I know it sounds like a stupid question but we all know that we’re supposed to say bismillah before eating anything but let’s say that you say bismillah before you eat a meal and then you get up and we’re gone for like 5 minutes and then you come back to the food should we say bismillah again or just eat the food since you already said it. The same goes for drinking. Do I say bismillah to drink after I eat or just drink? Then say alhamduillah after drinking and eating ?

Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and model I strongly suggest you to take the [tour] and check our [help].

Table manners in Islam (or when to say Bismi-Llah and al-Hamdu-li-Llah)
In Islam it is recommended to say "Bismi-Llah" when beginning to eat or drink, if one forgets it is allowed to do this later there are lot's of ahadith pointing at these:



I was a boy under the care of Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) and my hand used to go around the dish while I was eating. So Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) said to me, "O boy! Mention the Name of Allah and eat with your right hand, and eat of the dish what is nearer to you." Since then I have applied those instructions when eating.
(See for example here in Sahih al-Bukhari and Sahih Muslim)



The above hadith somewhat summarizes all essential table manners in Islam.



"When one of you eats food, then let him say: 'Bismillah.' If he forgets in the beginning, then let him say: 'Bismillah Fi Awwalihi Wa Akhirih (In the Name of Allah in its beginning and its end.)"
(See for example in Jami' at-Tirmidhi, in Sunan abi Dawod and in Sunan ibn Majah)



On the other hand, when finishing a meal one says al-Hamdu-li-Llah:



Whenever the Prophet (ﷺ) finished his meals (or when his dining sheet was taken away), he used to say. "Praise be to Allah Who has satisfied our needs and quenched our thirst. Your favor cannot by compensated or denied." Once he said, upraise be to You, O our Lord! Your favor cannot be compensated, nor can be left, nor can be dispensed with, O our Lord!"
(Sahih al-Bukhari)




Whenever the dining sheet of the Prophet (ﷺ) was taken away (i.e., whenever he finished his meal), he used to say: "Al-hamdu li l-lah kathiran taiyiban mubarakan fihi ghaira makfiy wala muWada` wala mustaghna'anhu Rabbuna."
“praise be to Allah abundantly and sincerely, of such a nature as is productive of blessing, is not insufficient, Abandoned, or ignored, O our lord.”
(Sahih al-Bukhari, translation see for example in sunnah.com: in Sunan abi Dawod)



When is saying Bismi-Llah permissible when not
Generally, one is highly recommended to start any (good) act, task, etc. either by saying "Bismi-Llah" -tehere are multiple examples of these in the sunnah- or some also said one should start each speech or talk by thanking Allah based on:

“Every important matter that does not start with praise of Allah, is devoid (of blessings).”
(See for example in Sunan ibn Majah or in Sunan abi Dawod)

On the other hand, it is highly sinful to start a sinful act by saying "Bismi-Llah". And by logic saying "al-Hamdu-li-Llah" if one concludes such a matter is also highly sinful and disrespectful not to say blasphemous.

Sister youre free to say bismillah before starting any task anytime. anyways its a short phrase to vocalize.
do you know what does bismillah mean?
